# Javascript/RegExp: Lookbehind Assertion is causing a "Invalid group" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, match, lookbehind

I'm doing a simple Lookbehind Assertion to get a segment of the URL (example below) but instead of getting the match I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=\#\!\/)([^\/]+)/: Invalid group
```

Here is the script I'm running:

```
var url = window.location.toString();
```

`url ==` http://my.domain.com/index.php/#!/write-stuff/something-else

```
// lookbehind to only match the segment after the hash-bang.

var regex = /(?<=\#\!\/)([^\/]+)/i; 
console.log('test this url: ', url, 'we found this match: ', url.match( regex ) );
```

the result should be `write-stuff`.

Can anyone shed some light on why this regex group is causing this error? Looks like a valid RegEx to me.

I know of alternatives on how to get the segment I need, so this is really just about helping me understand what's going on here rather than getting an alternative solution.

Thanks for reading.

J.

Comment: Can you give some example input string and what part of it must be matched by regex?

Comment: I've moved it from within the code block to the main example. Updated above. Please let me know if you'd like more detail and I will happily post it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe JavaScript does not support positive lookbehind.  You will have to do something more like this:

```
<script>
var regex = /\#\!\/([^\/]+)/;
var url = "http://my.domain.com/index.php/#!/write-stuff/something-else";
var match = regex.exec(url);
alert(match[1]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

Javascript doesn't support look-behind syntax, so the `(?<=)` is what's causing the invalidity error.  However, you can mimick it with various techniques: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Also you could use `String.prototype.match()` instead of `RegExp.prototype.exec()` in the case of global(/g) or sticky flags(/s) are not set.

```
var regex = /\#\!\/([^\/]+)/;
var url = "http://my.domain.com/index.php/#!/write-stuff/something-else";
var match = url.match(regex); // ["#!/write-stuff", "write-stuff", index: 31, etc.,]
console.log(match[1]); // "write-stuff"
```