# Regex match any string that isn't preceded by another string

Tags: javascript, regex

I suck at regex and I've been trying to get through this problem.
The problem is that I have a string and I want to match **any** "+" or "-" that aren't preceded by a "^".

Example string:

```
100x^-3+2x-10
```

The string above would be mathematically formatted or read as "one hundred times x to the -3 power, plus two times x, minus ten".

And I want to match the "+" before "2x" and the "-" before the "10" but **not** the "-" after "100x^". I hope it's not that confusing. I have tried the following reg, with no luck:

```
[^\^][\+|\-]
```

Obviously I'm missing a big detail somewhere.

Comment: Are you trying to match all the text after the operator or just trying to test if the string contains a plus or minus not preceded by a caret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to split by `+` or `-` :

```
"100x^-3+2x-10".replace(/([^^])[-+]/g,'$1@').split('@')
Output: ["100x^-3", "2x", "10"]
```

I used `@` as a temp char (but you can use a unique set of chars) to mark the signs not prefixed by `^` then safely split by the chosen temp char.

Comment: thank you, you actually look ahead of what I wanted this is the reason why i posted the question, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the old trick of simulating look behind by reversing the string, then matching against `/[\+\-](?!=\^)/`.

Comment: yeah this works too i guess i need to study regex a lot more, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It runs ok in chrome console, anyway you can try with : `"100x^-3+2x-10".match(/[^\^$]([\-|\+])/ig)` , I advice you to test your regex in the console of Google Chrome.

Comment: There is an problem with the character class. The pipe character does not need to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
/(?<!\^)[+-]/
```

Comment: im posting this comment just incase somebody finds this question useful, i had said this worked (the reg you gave) because i tried it in RegExr app, although I just tried in my script with match and i got the following error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<!\^)[+-]/: Invalid group", i don't know why the script can't make it work but my reg testing app does, oh well thanks anyway!

Comment: My appologies, it looks like Javascript does not support look-behinds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973669/javascript-regexp-lookbehind-assertion-is-causing-a-invalid-group-error