# convert C# regular expression to javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

This code is working for c#. when we are coming to java script it is not working.

regular expression in c#.

```
string regExp ="^(?!(\d)\1+$)(?!(012345678901|123456789012|234567890123|345678901234|456789012345|567890123456|678901234567|789012345678|890123456789|901234567890)$)(?!\d{9}000$)\d{12}$"
```

Somebody help me how to convert this into JavaScript.
Please let me now any conversion tool is there.

Comment: Could you show what you tried so far, how does your converted expression look like, and with what input data you tried it that didn't match which was matching in C#?

Comment: That's an interesting regex, what are you using it for?

Comment: Hint: Javascript doesn't support look-behind assertions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973669/javascript-regexp-lookbehind-assertion-is-causing-a-invalid-group-error

Comment: @Faust: So? There is no lookbehind assertion in that regex.

Comment: @Tim: Sorry, it's *lookahead* -- `?!`, and I didn't realize that these *are* supported, where lookbehinds are not. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 4):

There is a conversion tool available: [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com); it's not free, though (but totally worth it IMO).

Your regex is fine, you just need the proper JavaScript syntax:

```
var myregexp = /^(?!(\d)\1+$)(?!(012345678901|123456789012|234567890123|345678901234|456789012345|567890123456|678901234567|789012345678|890123456789|901234567890)$)(?!\d{9}000$)\d{12}$/;
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't know that RegexBuddy can do that! Where is this conversation option in RegexBuddy program? I couldn't find it.

Comment: @SonerGönül: You can paste a regex from any flavor ("Paste regex from a ... string" etc.), then click the "Use" tab and choose your output language. Done.