# generic convertion java regex to javascript regex

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I know there are a few questions regarding this topic, but for all of them I saw a specific regular expression to be converted from Java to JavaScript.

**However**, non of the answers contained some kind of an algorithm to do the conversion in a generic way.
So my question is if you know about an algorithm to convert Java regular expression to JavaScript regular expression? perhaps a third-party to do so?

Motivation and background: in client side, I get list of attributes from the server to render a form. Some of the form fields contain validation patterns to be checked in server later. For usability purposes, I want to be able to present the user the validation inline (like validation of an IP address), without maintaining regular expressions both in server and client.

Cheers,

Comment: I wouldn't expect there to be an algorithm to change a regex from Java-compatible to JavaScript-compatible because there are things a JavaScript regex is simply unable to do ([look-behind assertions for instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973669/javascript-regexp-lookbehind-assertion-is-causing-a-invalid-group-error)). For simpler regular expressions the same pattern should work in both.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is *generally* the same, but JavaScript has much less support for regex features.

For instance, lookbehinds are not supported, neither are possessive quantifiers, Unicode categories, named groups, the `s` option etc.

You can see a comprehensive feature comparison [on this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refbasic.html), but in the end JavaScript regexes are more or less a subset of Java regexes.

What you can do is write JS-compatible regexes and use them in Java, but if your Java regexes use features unavailable in JS you're out of luck.

You could also use the [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) library in JS to expand somewhat on the available features. It's a lib that converts some unsupported syntax to supported syntax, but it can't provide all the missing features.